# Please help me to keep my main window open

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a main window, that opens another window. I want to close this window and keep the main window open, but it closes the main window too.

I tried a lot of methods: setDefaultCloseOperation(), dispose(), setVisible(), but nothing worked for me.

In the main window I have this code

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    AdaugaComanda ac = new AdaugaComanda();
    ac.setVisible(true);
        }   
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new FereastraPrincipala().setVisible(true);
      }});}
```

and in the other window (that closes the main window when I close it) I have the following code

```
public class AdaugaProdus extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public AdaugaProdus() {
    initComponents();
    initComboBoxes();

}


public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            AdaugaProdus ad = new AdaugaProdus();
            ad.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add more relevant tags for your question to get the quick response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible simple solution: make the secondary window a dialog such as a JDialog, not a JFrame. An application will usually have only have one JFrame open at one time. A JDialog can hold as complex a GUI as any JFrame can, and when it closes, it will never close down the JVM as a JFrame can (as you're finding out). You also have the option of making the dialog modal or not, as the need dictates.

Having said this, please understand that while new information can be shown as a dialog that is owned by the JFrame, it can also be displayed by swapping components on the JFrame via a CardLayout -- it depends on what type of information that you're trying to show.